# How To Sort ADVANCED ALPHANUMERIC Strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

How to sort alphanumeric sorting in SQL Server like below

```
1A1
1A2
1A3
1A10
1A14
1A15
1A16
1A141
1A149
1A150
2A1
3B1
4C3
4C4
7E1
9999A7777
```

I have written the code like

```
SELECT [failure_mode_code]
FROM dst.Failure_mode
ORDER BY
    CAST(LEFT([failure_mode_code], PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', [failure_mode_code] + 'X') - 1) AS INT),
    SUBSTRING([failure_mode_code], PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', [failure_mode_code] + 'X'), LEN([failure_mode_code])),
    [failure_mode_code]
```

But I'm getting this result:

```
1A10
1A1
1A14
1A141
1A149
1A15
1A150
1A16
1A2
```

Here 1A2 should come after 1A1 and also 1A149 is coming before 1A15

can you help me with this sorting?

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question, now deleted. Why? You need to improve your existing question, not delete and open a new one.

Comment: And please teach yourself how to format code and data in your question

Comment: Seems like you're using the wrong datatype  perhaps a `hierachyid` or something would have been a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
Order By String(A, B .... ), FirstDigits, LEN(failure_mode_code), failure_mode_code;
```

This works because a longer number is also a bigger number

```
SELECT failure_mode_code    
FROM Failure_mode
order by SUBSTRING([failure_mode_code], PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', [failure_mode_code]), 1),
  CAST(LEFT([failure_mode_code], PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', [failure_mode_code] + 'X') - 1) AS INT), LEN(failure_mode_code), failure_mode_code;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/bow24o46)

Comment: the values are coming like this
c
0ANaN
0DNaN
Initial Action
Initial Action
1
1A
1A1
1A1
1A1
1A1
1A2
1A2
1A2
1A3
1A3
1A3
1A3
1A8
1A8
1A8
1A9
1A9
1A9
1B1
1B2
1B3
1C2
1C3
1D1
1E2
1F1
1F2
1K1
1M1
1N1
1Q2
1T1
1T2
1Y2
1Z2
1A10
1A15
1A15
1A15
1A16
1A16
1A16
1A17
1A17
1A17
1A18
1A18
1A19
1A19
1A20
1A20
1A20
1A20
1A37
1A37
1A37
But I want All the Alphabets of A To come in One Order After that B has to come

Comment: I made an update, can you have a look